# Doxygen | Store Documentation in a Database

Tags: c++, database, doxygen

I'm using Doxygen for a very very large C++ Code Base to generate HTML and Dot Graphs. The generated HTML pages are incredibly slow due to the massive amount of files. To speed up I thought there might be an implementation to manage the documentation content inside of a database.
Do you know of any plugin that allows this for Doxygen?
Or would you propose to use another tool instead?

Comment: Are you saying that they are slow to be generated or slow to view?

Comment: Both, actually. But I'm more concerned about the view. It's quiet obvious that the massive amount of classes and files slow down the web browser when opening the left-sided navigation pane. I was hoping that maybe there is a more performant way, e.g. loading content only partially on demand - maybe from a database.

Comment: Are you using the setting `CREATE_SUBDIRS` in the doxygen configuration file (Doxyfile) as this attempts to distribute the files over a number of directories and might speedup the display process a bit.